# How did the East Slavic pagans perceive the process of Christianization of Rus'?

Tags: russia, religion, christianity, reference, crowd-psychology

I read that the Christianization of Rus' was of great civilizational, political and cultural significance for the Eastern Slavs.

One of the notable aspects of this theme is the view, supported by some historical schools, of the supposedly rapid, almost universal and extremely welcome acceptance of the new religion by the then pagan community.

This goes against common sense. It is obvious that such an event could not have happened in one day and in an empty place. He certainly had many different prerequisites, and the methods of introducing a new religion could not be the most humane.

**My question is this:** how did the East Slavic pagan community perceive the introduction of a new religion and what key historical sources (documents, artifacts, events and phenomena) indicate the nature and duration of the Christianization of Rus'?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140854/discussion-on-question-by-dtn-how-did-the-east-slavic-pagans-perceive-the-proces).

Comment: @MCW I think my current draft is good enough, but the question is still not reopened. What else can be improved in it? I wrote as narrow a question as possible (to keep what I'm interested in). I cannot add any artifacts and documents, because I am not a professional historian and do not own historical material at the same professional level. I hoped to learn some of the materials in the process of discussing the issue.

Comment: Now that the question was completely rewritten, does the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianization_of_Kievan_Rus%27) answer it? As for the 2nd part (nature and duration), that's still unclear? You mean, apart from the fact that Russia, Ukraine and Belarus are still predominantly Christian (after over 1000 years, including 70 years of Communism)?

Comment: @dtn - That looks like a good question to me.  Please cite the assertion in the first sentence ("I read that" - read where? which schools? )  It would be stronger if you supported it with preliminary research.  ([Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)).  Nobody wants to answer with a source you've already read.

Comment: @MCW of course, I will try to give links to the literature with which I am familiar in order to build on something